# How would be possible to specify the order how the WHERE clause is evaluated?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to find records by one column but if there was no records i need to search in by another column but the first column has precedence.

Consider scenario:

```
find records matching column_1

if no records matching column_1, find records matching column_2

if records matching column_1 found, find the subset which also match column_2
```

How to construct such query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such queries (try to find records with certain criteria and if that fails try with other) are complicated.

Here is your criteria:

- If there exist records with matching column_1 and matching column_2, then show only these.
- If there exist records with matching column_1 and none of these matching column_2, then show none.
- If there exist no records with matching column_1, then show only records matching column_2

Looking at this more closely, it boils down to:

- If there exist records with matching column_1, then show only records matching column_ 1 and column_2
- If there exist no records with matching column_1, then show only records matching column_2

or:

- Show only records with matching column_2. If records with matching column_1 exist in the table, then filter such that column_1 must also match.

Here is the statement:

```
select * from mytable 
where column_2 = 'match2'
and
(
  column_1 = 'match1'
  or
  (select count(*) from mytable where column_1 = 'match1') = 0
);
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution, however can't understand the logic behind the `select count(*) = 0`

Comment: You count records in the table with matching column_1. Then you compare that value with zero.

Answer (score 1):

You don't care about the order of the parts of the `where` clause - they can be interchanged at will, and it's a good thing.

The usuall way to do what you're asking would be using the `or` operator:

```
where column_1 = @param or column_2 = @param
```

The query will not let you return the same row twice or more, it only applies the filters to each row once (logically).

What difference should there be between the three scenarios? If you want to return some extra status, you can use the select clause, for example like this:

```
select 
 case when column_1 = @param then 'Matched first!' 
 else 'Matched second!' end as Status
```

If you want to do that, you have to copy your query three times, and use `union all` to join the results from the three queries, eg. something like this:

```
select ... from ...
where column_1 = @param
union all
select ... from ...
where column_1 <> @param and column_2 = @param
```

etc.

Comment: That sounds like a plan. Have not been considering union concept. Thanks

Comment: Dimt, UNION doesn't work in your case, because you *either* want one result set *or* the other - depending on if records matching condition 1 exist. UNION can only glue toether *both* result sets.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Hmm, yeah, you're right. The best approach in this case might be using `@@ROW_COUNT` or a table variable.

Comment: @Thorsten just trying to implement your solution, but have to translate it first into my data scheme :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

select  from tablex , (select count(*) n from tablex where column1 = "condition") n where
(n.n <> 0 and column2 = "condition" and column1 = "condition") or (n.n = 0 and column2 = "condition")